# When using Android's Image Asset Studio why does it generate identical files for ic_launcher.xml and ic_launcher_round.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio we can right click the res folder and select New -> Image Asset. This will open the [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) where we can generate our Launcher icons. Typically users will choose "Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)"  for the Icon Type and choose an image for their Source Asset. Under Options we can opt into generating a Round Icon (API = 25).

At this point if we click Next and Finish, it will generate a few things:

1. ic_launcher_foreground.png(s) for every density mdpi->xxxhdpi to be used in the adaptive icon
2. ic_launcher_background.xml to represent the background color for the adaptive icon
3. ic_launcher.xml to define the adaptive icon using ic_launcher_foreground and ic_launcher_background
4. ic_launcher_round.png(s) for the round icon type for every density mdpi->xxxhdpi.
5. ic_launcher_round.xml. This is where it gets confusing.

The ic_launcher_round.xml is identical to ic_launcher.xml and **does not** use ic_launcher_round.png.

What is ic_launcher_round.xml for? Why is it the same as ic_launcher.xml? and why doesn't it use ic_launcher_round.png

The docs on the [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) don't explain it. Most repositories I've looked at show the same identical ic_launcher.xml and ic_launcher_round.xml.

Answer (score 1):

There are a set of android devices that use round icons (e.g. Pixel devices). The first of these devices appeared at api level 25.

They will look for the resource defined in the `roundIcon` attribute of the application tag in the AndroidManifest. For api level 25, which does not support adaptive icons, we just want to use the icon_round.png for the appropriate density.

For api level 26 and above, however, we actually don't need a special round icon at all. This is because [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive) are designed to work in multiple scenarios, which includes the round icon scenario. So for devices that use round icons that are running api level 26 and above, we just want to use a typical adaptive icon.

This means that the generated ic_launcher_round.png(s) are only needed specifically for devices that use round icons and are running api 25. This is why the GUI specifically says (API = 25) next to the generate round icons option.

So all round icon devices will use the value defined in the `roundIcon` attribute, which will map to the ic_launcher_round.png(s) for api 25 and below (effectively just api 25), and will map to ic_launcher_round.xml for api 26 and above (since it is placed in the mipmap-anydpi-v26 directory).

Some developers will actually redefine ic_launcher_round as a resource alias to ic_launcher.xml rather than duplicating the code to make this more clear.

For example:
`<item type="mipmap" name="ic_round_launcher">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>`

Comment: Thank you for sharing your research.  Good stuff : )